# SVG Image not Displaying from CSS File within Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, svg

I have an image in the assets/images directory called dot-matrix.svg that isn't displaying on my page.

I have a block in the CSS code that reads

```
.dotmatrix {
background: url('<% asset_path 'dot-matrix.svg' %>') 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;
height: 100%;
background-size: 50%;
width: 10%;
position: absolute;
```

}

In the view I have this:

```
<section id="content-receipt" class="clearfix">
   <div id="receipt-container">
   <div class="dotmatrix left"></div>
...
<div class="dotmatrix right"></div>
</div>
<div id="receipt-shadow"></div>
```

Any ideas on why this is not showing?  Note:  I tried changing the CSS code to from `asset_path` to `image_path` within the CSS, as well as changing `dot-matrix.svg` to `images\dot-matrix.svg` -- both with no success.

Comment: is there any error in console, can you check what is the path browser is looking up to load the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `=` in the erb-tags:

```
background: url('<%= asset_path 'dot-matrix.svg' %>') 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;
```

If this is not enough, use the developer tools of your browser, find the div, find the corresponding style-definition, and look what it displays for the background attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you put single quotes inside single quotes:

```
background: url('<% asset_path 'dot-matrix.svg' %>') 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;
```

You can fix it by exchanging one of the set of single quotes with double:

```
 background: url("<% asset_path 'dot-matrix.svg' %>") 50% 0% repeat-y #fff;
```